# Sue the Girl Scouts

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, civil-law

Some Girl Scouts have rebranded their Samoa cookies into [Momoas](https://www.thisisinsider.com%5Cjason-momoa-shirtless-photo-girl-scout-cookies-samoas-response-oscars-2019-2).

[image]

Could Jason Momoa sue the Girl Scouts for using his likeness without his permission? Or would this constitute some fair use or public figure loophole?

[image]

Comment: Is there an intent to link this modified cookie name to this individual? It isn't clear how they came up with it and that matters legally. The link in the question is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

The legal concept is [personality right](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_rights).

Of course, the more likely situation is that the Girl Guides have permission.

Comment: Since it's the sellers doing this aside from the organization, the suit would probably be brought against the parents of the sellers. It's unlikely that WB or Momoa would recover even a portion of the cost of the suit.

Comment: @RonBeyer depend on if the person doing it had ostensible authority or not

Comment: A: Girl Scouts, not Girls Guides. B: No permission, just the salesperson spurred on by her mother. C: No organizational approval.

Comment: @user6726 it doesn’t matter if there is actual approval, just ostensible approval. If a reasonable person would consider them to be a representative of the organization then, in the absence of fraud, they are. The circumstances of each case would decide. The link is broken so I can’t comment on the circumstances.

Comment: There is not even a claim to ostensible approval. Though official approval will presumably come 48 hours after the cease and desist petition is filed and the media storm ensues.

Comment: It also only violates the personality right (which differs from U.S. state to U.S. state and is not recognized in quite all of the 50 states), if the name is derived from and invokes that personality. The name "Bob's Burgers" for example, doesn't infringe on the personality rights of every Bob in the world, even if the chain isn't even named after a real Bob (you are privileged to do business under your own name even if it is a famous trademark of someone else).